# Puppeteer deployed to Heroku (Ubuntu) does not download PDF using Times New Roman font

Tags: express, pdf, heroku, puppeteer

I'm developing an app that needs to use Puppeteer to view a webpage and download it as a PDF for the end user. I'm using express.js as a server. The problem I'm having is that when developing locally on Windows, my PDF downloads look just like the source web page they're based off of, but when I deploy the app to Heroku which uses a Ubuntu based environment, the font is changed from Times New Roman to sans-serif.

Here is a snippet of my Puppeteer print pdf code:

```js
async function printPdf(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    ],
  })
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})

  const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' })
  await browser.close()

  return pdf
}
```

When I'm developing locally in Windows 10, the PDF downloads correctly:

localhost: source view on firefox that PDF references:
[image]

localhost: resulting PDF download, which correctly uses Times New Roman font:
[image]

My project is deployed to a free dynos using the [Heroku-20 Stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-20-stack), which is "based on Ubuntu 20.04". I've never used Linux, and am worried that may be the source of the problem.

When deployed, the web app correctly displays the font in firefox:
[image]

But the PDF download uses `font-family: sans-serif`:
[image]

How can I ensure my app deployed in a Linux environment downloads a PDF using the Times New Roman font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the Heroku Support team:

The library `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` has a post-install script (that installs the fonts) that's not running because we use `dpkg -x` (extract) not `dpkg -i` (install) in the apt buildpack. The installer is being downloaded and unpacked, but nothing of value is actually happening.
There are two workarounds either:

- download the font manually and add it to the repo and have Puppeteer call upon it, or
- use a different font, perhaps one already provided by the Ubuntu (fc-list in a dyno shows installed fonts) or is more easily downloadable and installable.

for my specific use-case, the issue was resolved by adding the font to my build and linking it via CSS. I found this blogpost helpful: [3 quick ways to add fonts to your React app](https://blog.greenroots.info/3-quick-ways-to-add-fonts-to-your-react-app)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft fonts are not available on Ubuntu out of the box. You can install [the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/ttf-mscorefonts-installer) to get Times New Roman, Arial, and other pre-Calibri Microsoft fonts.

On Heroku, you do that via [the Apt buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt):

1. First, add the buildpack to your app:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
   ```
2. Then, add an `Aptfile` listing the packages you wish to install. The Apt buildpack doesn't do dependency resolution so you may have to include a few dependencies manually.

   Something like this should do it:

   ```
   cabextract
   ttf-mscorefonts-installer
   wget
   xfonts-utils
   ```
3. Finally, commit your `Aptfile` and redeploy.

Comment: Heroku build fails, logs say: `Fetching .debs for ttf-mscorefonts-installer` `Reading package lists...` `Building dependency tree...` `Package ttf-mscorefonts-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.` `This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source` `E: Package 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' has no installation candidate`  `! Push rejected, failed to compile Apt app.` ... looking into solutions, but many do not apply to an Aptfile

Comment: That package is from the multiverse repository. It might not be available out of the box on Heroku. Will see if I can find a solution.

Comment: the example in https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt stated that you can "include links to specific .deb files", so I replaced `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` with a NA Mirror to the .deb file, from the list on https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/all/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/download. I used `http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.8ubuntu2_all.deb`. Build succeeded with the direct link, but PDF downloads do NOT use Times New Roman, still look the same with a sans-serif font.

Comment: 2 odd findings after using `heroku login` - `heroku run bash -a my-project`, 1) after connected and running `apt list`, many packages are listed but none of the 4 in my Aptfile, even though the build seems to indicate packages like `cabextract` were installed: https://pastebin.com/RnLDRXcC. 2) in bash, running `apt install cabextract` does not run: `W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock` - `E: Unable to locate package cabextract`. Perhaps I don't have permissions set up correctly to install custom packages, still investigating

Comment: `which cabextract` returns with `/app/.apt/usr/bin/cabextract`, but `which ttf-mscorefonts-installer` does not locate a directory. perhaps because it was fetched from a mirror, but build logs indicate it was installed - `-----> Installing ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.8ubuntu2_all.deb`

Comment: I don't believe `which ttf-mscorefonts-installer` _should_ return anything. IIRC that package is a wrapper to pull in an official archive of fonts from Microsoft to respect the licensing of the fonts. It isn't something you'd actually run manually.

Comment: unfortunately, the Heroku support team said this is not viable: "The library `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` has a post-install script (that installs the fonts) that's not running because we use `dpkg -x` (extract) not `dpkg -i` (install) in the apt buildpack. The installer is being downloaded and unpacked, but nothing of value is actually happening". This was a really great lead though, thanks for your tip!

Comment: Thanks for following up, and great job answering your own question, @auphynne!